# How to debug "The term 'X' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"?

Tags: powershell

Code:

```
G$Folders = Get-childItem C:\permissiontest\
$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit -bor [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::InheritOnly
$objType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 

foreach ($TempFolder in $Folders)
{
echo "Loop Iteration"
$Folder = $TempFolder.FullName

$acl = Get-Acl $Folder
$permission = "MRGROUP\ro","Read", $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission

$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
Set-Acl $Folder $acl
}
```

Error:

```
G$Folders : The term 'G$Folders' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.
At C:\script\aclper.ps1:1 char:1
+ G$Folders = Get-childItem C:\permissiontest\
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (G$Folders:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Well `G$Folders` isn't a command. What do you expect `G$name` will do? Presumably, get rid of the G and make it `$Folders = ` on the first line.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you want people to help, you should at least put some effort into your question. You literally dumped your script and error, with no context. You didn't even take the time to format it (which I just did for you).

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
G$Folders = Get-childItem C:\permissiontest\
```

with:

```
$Folders = Get-childItem C:\permissiontest\
```

That will get rid of this error

Comment: Thank you so much, and that worked successfully. What about if I wanted this applied to the parent folder and still include the subfolders and files?

Comment: Helo, please see below error message after i now try to execute it on the server. rror captured 
Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "No flags can be set.
Parameter name: inheritanceFlags"
At C:\temp\aclper.ps1:15 char:19
+ $acl.SetAccessRule <<<< ($accessRule)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: The issue is with inheritanceFlags, so looking at line 2 where you define that it looks like there is another typo -bor should likely be -or